# Opening a Unix executable with args on Mac Osx

Tags: macos, unix, terminal

How do I open a unix executable on Mac osx. I built a commandline application on Mac osx and I want to pass some arguments to it while executing from terminal.
But I am unable to open it from terminal as it doesnot recognise it.
all I can do is launch by double clicking on the executable. is there a way I can launch it with arguments. Pleas help.

Comment: So you want to run the unix binary with code from another app, or this is a question about using a unix binary in Terminal?

Comment: Have you tried ./myfile ? Also make it exec with chmod +x

Comment: its about using a unix binary from terminal.

Comment: Are you sure your binary is platform compatible? (IE was it compiled for darwin?)

Comment: i am trying to port a windows application on mac and its a command line tool.